# Let $A$ and $B$ be two non null matrices. For $AB=0$ , $A$ and $B$ should be singular such that their inverse do not exist. So is converse true?

Tags: linear-algebra

I mean if
$\det(A)=0$ and $\det(B)=0$; $A$ & $B$ are non null matrix.

So is it necessarily true that $AB$ will always be equal to $0$.

Comment: No, for example $A = B = \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0}$.

Comment: Det $AB$=Det $A\cdot $ Det $B$. If $x \cdot y=0$ if and only if any one of them is $0$.